# Stripping xml document of tags, removing line breaks and adding custom line breaks

Tags: c#, regex

I make a request to an xml web service, and get back a response. This response, being a stream, is then saved to a string. The problem is, the response is full of tags, CDATA, etc (as you would expect). There is no line breaking either, as to be expected.

I want to take this string, which represents an xml document, and strip it of all its tags but keep the actual values, and also, make sure that each record is in one line, so:

```
<Record>
  <name>adam</name>
  <telephoneno>000</telephonenumber>
</Record>
<Record>
  <name>mike</name>
  <telephoneno>001</telephonenumber>
</Record>
```

Will be transformed to:

```
adam 000
mike 001
```

Headings is an easy issue, but how could I achieve this? I've tried datatables and datasets but I don't think they have great support for achieving what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly what XSLT is for! It transforms XML files into a different output. In your case, you could use a relatively simple XSL transformation to output a list.

This might do it:

records.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<Records>
  <Record>
    <name>adam</name>
    <telephonenumber>000</telephonenumber>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <name>mike</name>
    <telephonenumber>001</telephonenumber>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

style.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="telephonenumber"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tested it with [this tool](http://www.netcrucible.com/xslt/xslt-tool.htm) and it works.

Comment: Generally if a transform emits text, you should set the xsl:output method to "text".  It won't change anything in this specific transform (though it will with some).  But I've seen XML tools that check the method to see if they should check the output for well-formedness, which you don't want here.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Haren's XSLT response is the best answer.

But alternatively if you're not actually wanting the response as XML you can return whatever it is that you DO desire from the web service (provided it's yours, rather than a third party service).

There's no rule that says a web service must return XML. Just make sure to serve the appropriate MIME-Type.